# XPath expr to check if current node is descendant

Tags: xml, xpath

I think an example will be better. If I have an xml like this, I would like to check if my current context node (based on where cursor is placed...this is perhaps not relevant ) is a descendant of node1[@attr="val"]/node2. So, if my cursor position is inside the first node2 or first node3 then it is a success scenario, if it is inside node1[@attr="val"] then it is a failure scenario.

```
<root>
      <node1 attr="val">
             <node2>
                    <node3>
                    </node3>
             </node2>
      </node1>
      <node1>
             <node15>
                    <node2>
                           <node3>
                           </node3>
                    </node2>
             </node15>
      </node1>
</root>
```

Also, if it is inside the second node3 then also it is a failure scenario since in that case node2 is not a direct child of node1 and also node1 does not have the required attribute.

Comment: I tried with ancestor-or-self::node1[@attr="val"]/node2....but in that case even if my cursor is just outside of node2 but inside node1 it still works. I would want that to fail. I am stuck with XPath 1.0.

Comment: Did you try just `ancestor::`? Like `ancestor::node1[@attr='val']`

Comment: That will not meet my requirement since I want it to be success when cursor position is inside `node1[@attr="val"]/node2`. So, `ancestor::node1[@attr='val']` will only check for node1 condition.

Comment: If that's what you want, `ancestor::node2/parent::node1[@attr='val']` would seem to capture that idea.